# What is the cheapest way to run a jsf application?

Tags: jsf, webserver, raspberry-pi, hardware

what do you think is the best and cheapest way to run a lightweight jsf application with database connectivity? i already thought about a raspberry pi, but i often read this one is really slow. are there other oppurtunities you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I think [RPi disro](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions) into a Raspberry Pi hard + Jetty as web server + HSQLDB database with be the choose.

Answer (score 1):

Depend what you call cheap.

You can waste money on a Raspberry Pi with a puny single core processor with very little ram and no Gigabyte networking capabilities.

Or you can send $20 more and get a Banana Pi.

I'd definitely consider the second choice.  It is so much better in every way compared to the Raspberry Pi, and has a decent enough speed to do awesome thing with.